# Formulas are not displayed properly

Tags: kindle, calibre, mobi, image, libreoffice

I usually create summaries of my university stuff with Open Office. I then export it as ODT and convert it to MOBI with Calibre in order to read it on my Kindle 4.
The problem is, my created [formulas](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319593/how-to-type-science-equations-in-libre-office) are not properly exported. The image just can't be shown.

Is there any way to export it properly? I don't want to use PDF, as I want to add a goto menu.

Comment: I fear that you'll have to convert the formulas to a graphic format (SVG would be the best option).

Comment: @mau: You mean directly in my document?

Comment: yes. In this way they should be converted in pictures.

Comment: Why you dont like pdf? I think pdf is the best option. if the size of the font is a problem, you can make a pdf with smaller size so text will be bigger.

Comment: pdf is a horrible option. It takes all formatting control away from your device. What happens when you open your MOBI file with the calibre reader?